# Implementation of the FNV-1a hash algorithm for 128-, 256-, 512- and 1024-bit

Tags: c#, performance, algorithm, .net, hashcode

A little over a year ago, I asked [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/39515/implementation-of-the-fnv-1a-hash-algorithm-for-32-and-64-bit) question. Since then, I've implemented the larger bit variations and am looking for any and all feedback - performance is obviously key when talking about FNV-1a, but having maintainable code and being correct and decently unit-testable are also paramount.

[GitHub](https://github.com/jslicer/FNV-1a/)

Base class `Fnv1aBigBase` (some method header documentation omitted for brevity):

```
public abstract class Fnv1aBigBase : HashAlgorithm
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The "wrap-around" modulo value for keeping multiplication within the number of bits.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly BigInteger modValue;

    /// <summary>
    /// The prime.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly BigInteger fnvPrime;

    /// <summary>
    /// The non-zero offset basis.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly BigInteger fnvOffsetBasis;

    /// <summary>
    /// The computed hash value.
    /// </summary>
    private BigInteger hash;

    protected Fnv1aBigBase(BigInteger modValue, BigInteger fnvPrime, BigInteger fnvOffsetBasis)
    {
        this.modValue = modValue;
        this.fnvPrime = fnvPrime;
        this.fnvOffsetBasis = fnvOffsetBasis;
        this.Initialize();
    }

    public override sealed void Initialize()
    {
        this.hash = this.fnvOffsetBasis;
    }

    protected override void HashCore(byte[] array, int ibStart, int cbSize)
    {
        for (var i = ibStart; i < cbSize; i++)
        {
            unchecked
            {
                this.hash ^= array[i];
                this.hash = (this.hash * this.fnvPrime) % this.modValue;
            }
        }
    }

    protected override byte[] HashFinal()
    {
        return this.hash.ToByteArray();
    }
}
```

---

`Fnv1a128`:

```
public sealed class Fnv1a128 : Fnv1aBigBase
{
    public Fnv1a128() : base(
            BigInteger.Parse("100000000000000000000000000000000", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier),
            BigInteger.Parse("0000000001000000000000000000013B", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier),
            BigInteger.Parse("6C62272E07BB014262B821756295C58D", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier))
    {
    }
}
```

---

`Fnv1a256`:

```
public sealed class Fnv1a256 : Fnv1aBigBase
{
    public Fnv1a256() : base(
            BigInteger.Parse("1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier),
            BigInteger.Parse("0000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000163", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier),
            BigInteger.Parse("0DD268DBCAAC550362D98C384C4E576CCC8B1536847B6BBB31023B4C8CAEE0535", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier))
    {
    }
}
```

---

`Fnv1a512`:

```
public sealed class Fnv1a512 : Fnv1aBigBase
{
    public Fnv1a512() : base(
            BigInteger.Parse("10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier),
            BigInteger.Parse("00000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000157", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier),
            BigInteger.Parse("0B86DB0B1171F4416DCA1E50F309990ACAC87D059C90000000000000000000D21E948F68A34C192F62EA79BC942DBE7CE182036415F56E34BAC982AAC4AFE9FD9", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier))
    {
    }
}
```

---

`Fnv1a1024`:

```
public sealed class Fnv1a1024 : Fnv1aBigBase
{
    public Fnv1a1024() : base(
            BigInteger.Parse("1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier),
            BigInteger.Parse("000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000018D", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier),
            BigInteger.Parse("0000000000000000005F7A76758ECC4D32E56D5A591028B74B29FC4223FDADA16C3BF34EDA3674DA9A21D9000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004C6D7EB6E73802734510A555F256CC005AE556BDE8CC9C6A93B21AFF4B16C71EE90B3", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier))
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: No sure answer, but it would probably result in better performance if you wrote a custom unchecked variant of `BigInteger` for each size, since you know the `modValue`, rather than relying on the default implementation that can grow to any size.

Comment: I have been surprised before to find that unchecked blocks can be slower than regular blocks. Try special casing the HashCore invocations where ibStart is 0 and cbSize is the length of the array -- a for loop from 0 to < array.length will optimize out the array checks. You may find it is faster. FNV1a is not considered a super-great algorithm, by the way.

Comment: Why the crypto tag? Fnv1a isn't a cryptographic hash.

Comment: Noted and corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things I like:

- Your abstract base class. It's a very wise design choice.
- You `protected` its constructor properly so that it's clear only child classes can call on the base class.
- Clear, simple, easy to read code.
- You `sealed` all of the concrete implementations.

Things I don't like:

- The XML doc comments on private fields. Leave the comments themselves, but the `///<SUMMARY>` tags are just clutter.
- In the loop, `ibStart` and `cbSize` could use more verbose names. Maybe it'd be clear to me if I had more domain knowledge, but I don't.

This is very clean, very nice code. Unless you've profiled the code and identified a slowdown somewhere, you're done here. Move along.

Comment: Thank you for the commentary. Just FYI `ibStart` and `cbSize` are named as such because that's their names in the base method `HashCore` in the .NET CLR. The XML doc I omitted on that method reads thus: "The offset into the byte array from which to begin using data." and "The number of bytes in the byte array to use as data.".

Comment: I had a feeling that I was missing some domain knowledge that would make them crystal clear. Thanks for filling in the blank.